# Problemas al graficar con Python

Tags: python-3.x

Tengo un fragmento de dataset. Como verán, está divido en meses y 3 especies de animales. Lo que se busca es realizar un grafico de barras para comprar la evolución a través del tiempo (el data termina en 2008). Para esto utilizo el siguiente código (tras lectura de datos).

```
# separar fechas e identificar los meses
df['Año']=df['Fecha_lance'].dt.year
df['Mes']=df['Fecha_lance'].dt.month
df['Dia']=df['Fecha_lance'].dt.day

# agrupar por mes
df.groupby(df['Mes'])

# calcular promedio de una especie (repetir x3)

mer=df.groupby(df['Mes'])['Mer_comun'].mean()
mer

# configurando el tamaño de la figura
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
# dibujando los graficos
n, bins, patches = plt.hist(cola[ ], 12, 
                            facecolor='red', label='cola')
n, bins, patches = plt.hist(mer[ ], 12, 
                            facecolor='green', label='mer')
n, bins, patches = plt.hist(besugo[ ], 12, 
                            facecolor='blue', label='besugo ')
# agregando la leyenda
plt.legend(loc='upper left')

# mostrando el resultado
plt.show()
```

Al ejecutar esto, me aparece SyntaxError.
¿Alguien me explica dónde tengo el error?
¿Qué hago mal o que no estoy haciendo y debería?

[image: dataset]

Comment: Ah, sí. Ya sé qué error dices :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
# dibujando los graficos
n, bins, patches = plt.hist(cola[:], 12, 
                            facecolor='red', label='cola')
n, bins, patches = plt.hist(mer[:], 12, 
                            facecolor='green', label='mer')
n, bins, patches = plt.hist(besugo[:], 12, 
                            facecolor='blue', label='besugo ')
```

El error de sintaxis está en que escribes `cola[]`, cuando lo que debes hacer para recuperar todos los valores de `cola` es `cola[:]`. Lo mismo con `mer[:]` y `besugo[:]`.

[Más información (en inglés)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation)

(Ese es el error de sintaxis por el que preguntas, pero hay más errores en el código)

Comment: muchas gracias! y si me percate que tengo una falla en el código porque el grafico no salio como esperaba. Sabes donde podría buscar mas información?